# Magento ajax cart translation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

whole Magento website was in Lithuanian, however, decided to add English and make it multilangual. Everything went find, and basically everything is in it's place, execpt not sure how to translate Ajax messages.

http://s2.postimg.org/a323wd4fd/Untitled.png

Code looks like:

```
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
                onCreate    : function() {
                    _this.g.warn("Vykdoma", {
                        life: 5
                    });
```

Is it possible to make it multilang?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can take advantage of the magic translator function in magento `$this->_("To Translate!")`. Because PHP always runs first I don't see how you can not do the following:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
    onCreate    : function() {
        _this.g.warn(<?php echo $this->_("Vykdoma"); ?>, {
        life: 5
    }
});
```

Then add the `translate.csv` into your theme locale folder.

```
Vykdoma,Ongoing
```

Comment: Thanks, thought that in ajax files this won't work.
Tried it, and ain't sure why, but products stop loading on the front page, and every process that is with ajax does not work any more.

Comment: Are you using a *.js file, or is this ajax in a phtml template?

Comment: It's .js file.

ajaxcart.js

Comment: Sorry, might sound stupid, can you give an example?
Never worked with php, not talking about ajax and .js

Comment: Check this out http://www.webspeaks.in/2013/10/3-ways-to-add-javascript-translations-in-magento.html